# (Unity) The rigged model looks smooth on computer, but has mesh problems on mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine

Our animated models have mesh deformation. But this problem is not experienced on the computer. Only seen on mobile platforms. Unity quality([quality SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnkQD.png)) settings very high.
Sample:[penguin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBLnr.jpg) and [monkey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DADMm.jpg)

Why is the problem caused? thank you for your help

Comment: Please show the quality settings. and which mobile platform?

Comment: Android and ios platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still select the Fastest quality, click this arrow then select a level to take effect for final release.

[image: quality settings]